# Unable to map multiple values using mapstruct and lombok @Value and @Builder, works with @Data

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have a mapping that looks like this

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring") 
public interface CreateCdiMapper {
    CreateCdiMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CreateCdiMapper.class);


    @Mapping(source = "data.attributes.deviationShortDescription", target = "fields.summary")
    @Mapping(source = "included.genericDeviationId", target = "fields.deviationId")
    DeviationDto jsonToCreateJiraCdi(Deviation createDeviation);
}
```

The target is made immutable using lomboks `@Value`, and also has `@Builder`.
My mapping works fine if I comment out either of fields, i.e.

```
//@Mapping(source = "data.attributes.deviationShortDescription", target = "fields.summary")
@Mapping(source = "included.genericBrandInternalReleation", target = "fields.deviationId")
DeviationDto jsonToCreateJiraCdi(Deviation createDeviation);
```

and

```
@Mapping(source = "data.attributes.deviationShortDescription", target = "fields.summary")
//@Mapping(source = "included.genericBrandInternalReleation", target = "fields.deviationId")
DeviationDto jsonToCreateJiraCdi(Deviation createDeviation);
```

both work fine. I can see that lomboks Builder is being used in the generated classes. But if I leave both mappings uncommented as in the first example above, I get these errors saying the both fields are missing write accessors.

```
"summary" has no write accessor in Fields for target name "fields.summary".
"deviationId" has no write accessor in Fields for target name "fields.deviationId"
```

I have in my build.gradle

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
    mapstructVersion = "1.4.1.Final"
    lombokVersion = "1.18.16"
    lombokMapstructBindingVersion = "0.2.0"
}
implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${lombokMapstructBindingVersion}"
```

Can someone please help me understand why this happens? If I remove `@Value` and `@Builder` and instead go with `@Data`, everything works fine.

Adding relevant classes

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Deviation{
    Fields fields;
}

@Value
@Builder
public class Fields {
    String summary;
    String deviationId;
}
```

Comment: How do `Deviation` and `DeviationDto` classes look like?

Comment: I've added the target classes. The sources are generated, but they are basic POJOs with getters/setters, no lombok there.

Comment: I filed an issue with mapstruct here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2348